# How to make text fit the full height of a container element

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is coloring the text red, yellow, green blue.  Right now there is no red as the following picture shows.  The height of the text element goes from the top of the screen to the bottom of the text, as does the container element.  To get the red showing I need to get the text the full height of the element, which in the picture would be the top of the black background.  I've tried several variations trying to style it with flex and table.

[image]

If I remove the height from the container element it centers the text vertically but as this pic shows it still is not full height to show more color top and bottom.  Any ideas?

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;800&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 8rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  /* this changes nothing */
  align-self: stretch;
  /* this also changes nothing */
}

#header {
  /* I've tried flex and align stretch etc. here also without success */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0% 25%, yellow 25% 50%, green 50% 75%, blue 75%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">WORD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `line-height` property?

Comment: I set `line-height` to 1 in this example, I can't tell however, wether the font is intended to look like this or not. https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/yLObYop

Comment: I hadn't tried that but I just did and ```line-height``` doesn't change the height of the text it just changes its position.

Comment: So setting `line-height` to 1 and `font-size` to `7rem` shows the text in its full glory, it however isn't the same size as the container. https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/yLObYop

Comment: @Simplicius I updated the second picture to try to better show the intended look.  As you can see the text is not the height of the element.  If it were then the red, yellow, green, and blue would show in the same amount on "WORD"

Comment: @eoja, Yes, indeed, that's what I figured.

Comment: line height generally about 20% larger as the font-size. What you can do is reverse this height back. If you want that your font height to be equal to the size of the element you can add 20% to it's value. By tweaking with some numbers you can get this: https://jsfiddle.net/csmLnwzk/ So it might be better to tweak the background-position instead.

Comment: @JensIngels Thanks, line-height gets it close and works as long as the letters are all caps (which in my case they are).  But background position and size is probably better to use if there are lowercase letters or characters not the same size because line-height will cut them off.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of the font. If you add characters like `Â` you will see the red part so your text is already taking the needed space.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;800&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 8rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0% 25%, yellow 25% 50%, green 50% 75%, blue 75%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">WORÂÄ</div>
</div>
```

And if you add characters like `j` you will also get surprised with some overflow:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;800&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 8rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0% 25%, yellow 25% 50%, green 50% 75%, blue 75%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">WjRÂÄ</div>
</div>
```

In your particual case you can play with the `background-size` to get the coloration you want considering that you will not have characters like `j` or `Â`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;800&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0% 25%, yellow 25% 50%, green 50% 75%, blue 75%);
  /* an approxiamtion based on your case, you may need to change it */
  background-size:100% 60%; 
  background-position:0px 54%;
  /**/
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">WORD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoted. Because both examples cut the text at the bottom part, I guess it's not in his intention.

Comment: @Simplicius hmm, how can the text be cut if I did change nothing in the first example? also in the second one (only background property is changed)

Comment: Well, run the code snippet. But for you, the text in the first snippet gets pushed down because of the special letters "Â" and "Ä", in the second on, again just run the code, the size of the container is meat, and since the text is defined as a background-image, it ends as well.

Comment: @Simplicius letters cannot push text, the font metric define the position/size of the text whataver the letter you are using .. not sure what you are seeing .. the first snippet give the exact same result as the snippet in the question since no CSS is changed

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for taking a look.  Your third snippet is close to what I'm trying to achieve.  However, the colors are not 25% of the height of the text, they are close but off a little.  I tried messing with the background size and position percentages but could not get more than just close.  If I could make the text fill the element then all the colors would be at 25% of the text height.

Comment: @eoja you can only get close due to the nature of the font and the font metric like I have explained. even if you try to make the text full height you need to approximate it, so in all the case it a "getting close" exercise, either by adjusting the height of the background properties